# How to configure a Lookup No Match Output in SSIS 2005

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSIS 2012, there is a No Match Output on the lookup transformation. However, i just released that a similar output is not available for the lookup transformation in SSIS 2005.

How can one achieve the same kind No Match functionality in SSIS 2005 with the lookup transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why Don't you send `No match rows` to `error output`?

or configure as [said here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2010/02/09/ssis-snack-configuring-an-ssis-2005-lookup-transformation-for-a-left-outer-join.aspx)

or [see this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9452899c-9eeb-4e9b-bffc-a4b475552501/ssis-2005-lookup-component-not-able-to-detect-existing-rows-in-a-table?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: Sending No match rows to error output does not add new rows. It simply stops insertion of duplicate rows. Can it configured in a way that new rows are inserted but duplicates are left out?

Comment: The lookup component does not add new rows, it simply augments the existing row with additional data. Your original question is about the no match functionality. Do you have two different questions here or is the original question incomplete?